# Test Class for SOQL Query Apex Class

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, query, developer

I have created an apex class that queries three objects to create a list of records. I use this with a Visualforce page to display a table. It works just fine however my test class isn't giving me any code coverage so I'm sure I'm going about this wrong. I started with a test class that was just creating records for each of these objects and then tried to create a list that would pull the same information that was being queried in the apex class. I'm new at apex so if you need more information, please let me know.

APEX CLASS

```
public with sharing class RecentStatusReports{
public List<PPM_Project__c> ProjectRecords {get; set;}
public RecentStatusReports(){
ProjectRecords =
[SELECT Id, Name, PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name, Project_Status__c, complete__c, project_manager__r.Name, 
(SELECT Id, Budget_Status__c, Project_Schedule__c, Items_for_Management_Attention__c, Status_Date__c, Name, Open_Items__c, Team_Member__c, Summary_Project_Status__c, Overall_Status__c  
FROM R00N80000002lZ2OEAU__r WHERE Project_Schedule__c != 'Green' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM PPM_Project__c 
WHERE IsDeleted=false AND (PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name LIKE 'technical%' OR PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name LIKE 'training%' OR PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name 
LIKE 'product%' OR PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name LIKE 'solution%') AND project_Status__c='Active' AND Last_Status_Report_Date__c !=NULL ORDER BY PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name];
}
 }
```

TEST CLASS

```
@isTest 
public with sharing class TestingMostRecentStatusReports{
public List<PPM_Project__c> ProRecs {get; set;}
public TestingMostRecentStatusReports(){
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
                    User u = new User(Alias = 'lumi', Email='Luminex@testorg.com', 
                    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Tester', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='Luminex@testerorg.com');

        System.runAs(u) {
                     Portfolio__c port = new Portfolio__c(Name = 'Test1StatusReport', Year__c = 'Draft');    
                     insert port; 

                     PPM_Project__c pro = new PPM_Project__c(Name = 'A1TestStatusReport', Project_Status__c = 'Active', Project_Type__c = 'New', Portfolio__c = port.id , 
                     Business_Unit_Sponsor__c = 'Customer Service', Project_Goal__c = 'Grow Business', Delivered_Business_Asset__c = 'Application', Budgeted_Hours__c = decimal.valueof('20') );    
                     insert pro; 

                     Status_Report__c SR = new Status_Report__c(Project__c = pro.id , Status_Date__c = date.today() , Project_Schedule__c = 'Yellow' );
                     insert SR;

    ProRecs =
    [SELECT Id, Name, PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name, Project_Status__c, complete__c, project_manager__r.Name, 
    (SELECT Id, Budget_Status__c, Project_Schedule__c, Items_for_Management_Attention__c, Status_Date__c, Name, Open_Items__c, Team_Member__c, Summary_Project_Status__c, Overall_Status__c  
    FROM R00N80000002lZ2OEAU__r WHERE Project_Schedule__c != 'Green' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
    FROM PPM_Project__c 
    WHERE IsDeleted=false AND (PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name LIKE 'technical%' OR PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name LIKE 'training%' OR PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name 
    LIKE 'product%' OR PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name LIKE 'solution%') AND project_Status__c='Active' AND Last_Status_Report_Date__c !=NULL ORDER BY PPM_Project__c.Portfolio__r.Name];
    }
     }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test class isn't actually testing the underlying class, you need something like this

```
@isTest 
private class TestingMostRecentStatusReports{
private static void testMethod1 () {
  // Mock data
  Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
  User u = new User(Alias = 'lumi', Email='Luminex@testorg.com', 
                    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Tester', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='Luminex@testerorg.com');
  insert u;
  System.runAs(u) {
     Portfolio__c port = new Portfolio__c(Name = 'Test1StatusReport', Year__c = 'Draft');    
     insert port; 

     PPM_Project__c pro = new PPM_Project__c(Name = 'A1TestStatusReport', Project_Status__c = 'Active', Project_Type__c = 'New', Portfolio__c = port.id , 
                     Business_Unit_Sponsor__c = 'Customer Service', Project_Goal__c = 'Grow Business', Delivered_Business_Asset__c = 'Application', Budgeted_Hours__c = decimal.valueof('20') );    
     insert pro; 

     Status_Report__c SR = new Status_Report__c(Project__c = pro.id , Status_Date__c = date.today() , Project_Schedule__c = 'Yellow' );
     insert SR;

     // now test the prod class as mocks are done
     RecentStatusReports rsr = new RecentStatusReports();
     System.assertEquals(/*however many rows you expect*/, rsr.ProjectRecords.size() );
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: so should the following work in the System.assertEquals line?:
System.assertEquals(1, rsr.ProjectRecords );
  }
 }
}

Comment: my bad, a typo - see corrected answer